# Managing passwords

Tags: password, adduser

I've created as administrator other account using the command `sudo adduser newuser`. The system asked for a UNIX password and I provided it, but now I want to create a sudo password for that account. I mean, I want that the user can install packages but only if he/she knows a password different to the UNIX password.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can set up sudo to use a password database different from the system default. This answer from unix stackexchange tells how:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94646/49439

Answer (score 0):

sudo just enables one to run privileged commands from a normal user account.  It does this by verifying that the user is who they say they are (by asking for their password) and referencing the sudo configuration in /etc/sudoers to validate that they can indeed run the command they are requesting.

In your case, you need to grant the user the ability to run apt-get.

Comment: I don't understand completely what you mean. If I type ```sudo apt-get foo``` it asks for a password, if I type the UNIX password it says: username is not in the sudoers file, I want to add username to the sudoers file but with the requirement of a different password

Comment: If this is solved granting the user ability to run apt-get, how can I do that?

Comment: See 'man 5 sudoers' for more info about how to grant users sudo capability.  Also, see Mark Plotnick's comment about how to have it look into a different password database.  I still learn something new every day!